# Add package link in a custom folder

Tags: dart, dart-pub, rikulo

I have create a folder (named *webapp*) in a Dart project where I put some server side classes. When I run `pub install` ( or `pub update` ), to import the libraries that I use in the project, the dependencies are correctly download and some link to this folder are created in some default folders ( eg: *web*, *out* ecc ).

there is a way to generate automatically a link to the package folder in my *webapp* ( or any custom folder ) folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to make `pub` generate `packages` in a not standard directory.

In [pub install documentation](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/pub-install.html) you can read the section [Linked `packages` directories](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/pub-install.html#linked-packages-directories) :

> It assumes your package is laid out according to the [package layout guide](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html), and creates a linked `packages` directory in `bin/`, `test/`, and `example/`, as well as their subdirectories.

Comment: Ok, I also thought that it was so, but I asked to be sure. I put my server code in webapp folder because i use the library [stream](http://docs.rikulo.org/stream/latest/Getting_Started/Introduction.html) and the guide says to do so.

Comment: The `webapp` folder seems to be a subfolder of `web` in [Hello World](http://docs.rikulo.org/stream/latest/Getting_Started/Hello_World.html). That's why it works.